# Шифрование текста RSA c++

Tags: c++, алгоритм, шифрование, rsa, encryption

где можно найти легкую и понятную реализацию шифрования текста rsa в c++

пересмотрел множество видео и реализаций но либо все сделано до безумия нагромождено и сложно либо программа вообще не работает

заранее всем спасибо за помощь

Comment: Наверное, написать самому... Как только вы это сделаете, так сразу она станет понятной...

Comment: после прочтения нескольки десятков источников я уже способен понять как математически и частично по коду понял как это реализовуется
только вот ничего всеровно не получается

Comment: Приведите пример вашей реализации и напишите, что именно не получается и вам постараются помочь

Comment: Вполне можно использовать публично доступный код вроде [этого](https://gist.github.com/lillypad/f5de36cd9769cfaa54af80b4b331184e)